# Boxen install mysql version?

Tags: puppet, boxen

I am trying to use boxen for installing software on new computers and would like to know if there is a way to install a specific version of mysql (5.5.29) using the puppet-mysql module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in [their readme](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/mysql) for the module under parameters:

> package_ensure
>
> What to set the package to. Can be present, absent, or **version**.